# How to move images independently

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code should display an alert when an image is clicked and then the movement buttons should move the image.  The problem occurs when you click on the next image.  The movement buttons now operate on the images that were previously clicked as well.  Note: I need to do this without setting up id's on each image

Also, why doesn't the fiddle work when I place my js in the js box?  It seems to only work when added as a script to the html

jsfiddle   [farm animals](https://jsfiddle.net/rss81/ztwhLxsn/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("img").click(function() {
    alert("a " + this.alt + " was clicked on!");
    var image = $(this);

    $("#up").click(function() {
      var offset = image.offset();
      $(image).offset({
        top: offset.top - 5,
        left: offset.left
      })
    });

    $("#down").click(function() {
      var offset = image.offset();
      $(image).offset({
        top: offset.top + 5,
        left: offset.left
      })
    });

    $("#left").click(function() {
      var offset = image.offset();
      $(image).offset({
        top: offset.top,
        left: offset.left - 5
      })
    });

    $("#right").click(function() {
      var offset = image.offset();
      $(image).offset({
        top: offset.top,
        left: offset.left + 5
      })
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: It looks like a scope problem. Try moving the movement button out of the click image event!

Comment: You have to click the "JavaScript" button in that section of the Fiddle and tell it what external library you are using. Then you can include the JS in the JS section:  https://jsfiddle.net/4d04tgcf/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining additional button click handlers every time an image is clicked. That means that you can click multiple images and move them at once, but also that you can click the same image multiple times, and the buttons will be moving the image a greater distance each time.

You should define button click handlers only once, and let the image click handler just reassign the value of `image`.

```
var image;

$("img").click(function() {
  alert("a " + this.alt + " was clicked on!");
  image = $(this);
});

$("#up").click(function() {
  var offset = image.offset();
  $(image).offset({
    top: offset.top - 5,
    left: offset.left
  })
});

$("#down").click(function() {
  var offset = image.offset();
  $(image).offset({
    top: offset.top + 5,
    left: offset.left
  })
});

...
```

See a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/7ovsfb1o/)

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. The problem is that you were redefining the `image` variable inside your `click` handler, and it should be outside. See the modified code (partial)

```
  //this is the variable you will use in all your click handlers
  var image;
  $("img").click(function() {
    //here you assign a specic image to it
    image = $(this);

    $("#up").click(function() {
      //in every handler, just to be sure, check if ANY image has been clicked
      if(!image) return;
      var offset = image.offset();
     ...
```